# User redirect to specific URL after logging in

Tags: redirect

I'm trying to redirect a user to a specific post after logging in. This post is the latest post of a custom post type where the author is the current logged in user.

I currently have to following code to get the specific post url:

```
function member_permalink () {  
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'cursist',
        'author' => $user_id
    );

    $current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );       
    $post_link =  get_permalink( $current_user_posts->ID );

    return $post_link;  
}
```

And the code to redirect the user after login (taken from the Codex)

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        //check for subscribers
        if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage 
            $redirect_to =  member_permalink();
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

However I get redirected to WP-admin instead of the post.

If I do a var_dump of the function to get the specific post url I get the following in return (which is the data that I want):

```
string(52) "http://example.com/cpt-slug/niels-pilon/"
```

I'm probably doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Comment: Hey Niels :) member_permalink() returns the URL to a post authored by the current user - if there is any. Though in line 5 of my_login_redirect(), you are only redirecting the current user if they are a "subscriber". Pretty sure this is the culprit here.

Comment: What is the role of given user?

Comment: The user that's redirected has a role of subscriber. The function is fine if I change the `$redirect_to` to `home_url()`. The author of the CPT has also a role as member as I create the CPT with a function when registering a new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the `$user` as a parameter to `member_permalink()` instead of relying on `get_current_user_id()`.

From the codex about the `login_redirect` filter:

> The $current_user global may not be available at the time this filter
>   is run. So you should use the $user global or the $user parameter
>   passed to this filter.

Sample updated code:

```
function member_permalink( $user = null ) {

    if ( null == $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    } else {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'cursist',
        'author'      => $user_id,
        'numberposts' => 1,
    );

    $current_user_posts = get_posts( $args ); 

    if ( empty( $current_user_posts ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_link = get_permalink( $current_user_posts[0] );

    return $post_link;  
}

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        //check for subscribers
        if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to another URL
            $redirect_to = member_permalink( $user );
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

[edit]: I made the `$user` parameter optional to provide flexibility in case you use this function without parameters in some other places.

Comment: Thanks but I only get an Trying to get property of non-object notice reffering to `$post_link          = get_permalink( $current_user_posts->ID );`

Comment: Indeed, now that you mention it I wonder how this function was working before, considering get_posts() returns an array of objects (and not an object) even if there is only one result. I just edited my answer to hopefully fix this.

Comment: After `$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args )`, you should check if there are any results: `if (is_array($current_user_posts) && count($current_user_posts) > 0)`.

Comment: @NielsPilon brilliant, glad I could help :)
Good point @nmr, I just updated the answer. `get_posts()` always returns an array - an empty one if there are no results - so I'm just checking that it is not empty. Also `get_permalink()` accepts either an id or a `WP_Post` object, so I removed the "->ID" part to only pass `$current_user_posts[0]`